# Посоветуйте хостинг для сайта на Flask (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, веб-сервер, хостинг

Посоветуйте хостинг для сайта на Flask (python)
Когда гуглил выскакивала одна рекламма

Comment: Любой VPS/VDS-хостинг.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/
- есть возможность вообще не платить (бесплатный тариф), для учёбы (когда сайтом почти никто не пользуется) - идеально)

Comment: Я знаю про этот хостинг, и пытался на него поставить сайт, но почему-то не работает подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136221/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-flask-python-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-everywhere

Comment: Для тех, кто не хочет переходить и смотреть, насколько понимаю, в итоге всё заработало, просто автор вопроса не до конца разобрался в том, как хостить на pythonanywhere

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud/ Amazon AWS.

1. https://cloud.google.com
2. https://aws.amazon.com/

И там и там бесплатный пробеый период в 12 месяцев.

Comment: А  они нуждаются в дополнительной настройке? например установить Flask или еще чтото? если да, то где посмотреть документацию?

Comment: Документация есть на самом хостинге, ее можно найти в разделе "Поиск" на обоих ресурсах. Однако более вероятно что на хостинге есть сервера с предустановленными модулми, ведь это ресурсы специализированного использования, Более чем уверен, что разработчики позаботились о удобстве использования их хостов IT специалистами.