# Не запускается Flask (python) сайт на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

Не понимаю в чем проблема, вроде все сделал правильно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда перехожу по ссылке, то получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть проблемма в том, что я не подключил домен?

Comment: Укажите серверу flask хост как `0.0.0.0`. При подключении к серверу указывайте внешний адрес сервера (это не `0.0.0.0`), это можно узнать, например, сделав запрос на какой-нибудь сайт myip. С pythonanywhere не работал, возможно у него своя логика работы с серверами

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что вы переходите по локальному IP: *127.0.0.1*
Этот IP адресс обозначает LocalHost. Т.е вы пытаетесь перейти на хостинг расположенный у вас на компьютере. Если на компьютере не установлен сервер  - это невозможно. Другими словами вы переходите сами к себе. IP адресс *127.0.0.1* является служебным. **Если простым языком - *127.0.0.1* - IP адрес вашего же компьютера у вас в домашней сети.** Чтобы перейти на сайт вам нужно либо узнать IP сервера на котором он стоит, либо **прикрепить домен**.

Comment: тоесть мне надо подключить домен?

Comment: Вам нужно подключить домен или узнать IP сервера, если досуп по нему разрешен на данном хостинге. Читайте мой овтет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать web приложение во вкладке Web, потом в созаданном flask_app.py добавляете свой код (или при создании приложения прописываете путь к основному файлу приложения). Приложение будет доступно по адресу `имя_пользователя.pythonanywhere.org`.

При изменениях в файлах приложения, чтобы изменения отобразились на сайте, нужно перезагружать приложение (зеленая кнопка `Reload имя_пользователя.pythonanywhere.org`).